# Regex: Change Headlines Texts to uppercase

Tags: php, regex

In my Website i want to use the german letter ß, which only exists as a lowercase letter. Though i want all my headlines to be shown in uppercase letters (capitalize), i use `font-transform: uppercase`. But that replaces the ß letter with a uppercase SS, which is not wanted due to certain design and programming features.

So i was thinking about a `preg_replace_callback`, that changes all letters in the headlines in my HTML code to their uppercase letters.

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/(<h\d>)(.*)(<\/h\d>)/', function($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . mb_strtoupper($matches[2], 'UTF-8') . $matches[3];
}, $content);
```

That works well on headings with no special attributes or nested links etc. As i'm a total newbie in regular expressions i don't know how to write those.

Basically `<h2 class="heading-italic"><a href="http://www.google.de">Google</a></h2>`should become to `<h2 class="heading-italic"><a href="http://www.google.de">GOOGLE</a></h2>`

How would my regular expression look, that is also catching headings with attributes and also (multiple) nested elements?

Comment: I'd like to recommend two things: 1) Stick with the double S for capitalized ß, as this is widely accepted to be "correct". There's a reason CSS does it this way. It's like mixing minus/dash (-/–), apostrophe/accent, [plenken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plenken) and so on: The user understands it, yet it's wrong. 2) [Do not parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3890673) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `/(<h\d>)(.*)(<\/h\d>)/` to this one:

```
 $newregex = '/(<h\d.*?>)(<a .*?>)?(.*)(<\/a>)?(<\/h\d>)/' ;

 $content = preg_replace_callback( $newregex , function($matches) {
     return $matches[1] . mb_strtoupper($matches[3], 'UTF-8') . $matches[5];
 }, $content);
```

Note `mb_strtoupper($matches[3], 'UTF-8')` and `[3]` is used for new regex and 3rd group. group2 and group4 are optional.